# Invalid use of property in vb6

Tags: vb6

I Have recordset `rc1` that reads values from txt file. The fields are `rtn`, `amt`, `name`. Now I get the data from table `t_rec` and assigned it to another recordset `rc2`. and  compare with the recordset `rc1`.

```
If rd1.Fields![AccountNbr] = rc2.Fields![RTProvided] Then
      Set rc2.Fields![ClaimStatus] = "c"
          rc2.Fields![DateClosed] = CqDate
          rc2.Fields![Audit_LastUpdated] = CqDate
          rc2.Fields![Audit_UserAdded] = "System"
```

If i compile that program i am getting errr like Invalid use of property in vb6. Can you help me.

```
Sub DneFroceClose()

CqDate = Format(Date, "dd/MM/yyyy")

Set rcdreclamation = New ADODB.Recordset
With rcdreclamation
    .ActiveConnection = objConn
    .Source = "SELECT * FROM T_DATA_reclamation"
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Open
End With

frmDNELoad.lblStatus.Caption = "Adding record " & lngRecCount & " of " & rcdreclamation.RecordCount & " to database."
frmDNELoad.Refresh

rcdDNE.Open
rcdreclamation.Open
rcdDNE.MoveFirst
rcdreclamation.MoveFirst

Do Until rcdDNE.EOF

  Do Until rcdreclamation.EOF

     If rcdDNE.Fields![AccountNbr] = rcdreclamation.Fields![RTProvided] Then
      Set rcdreclamation.Fields![ClaimStatus] = "c"
          rcdreclamation.Fields![DateClosed] = CqDate
          rcdreclamation.Fields![Audit_LastUpdated] = CqDate
          rcdreclamation.Fields![Audit_UserAdded] = "System"
          Exit Do
     Else
     rcdreclamation.MoveNext
     End If

  Loop
   rcdDNE.MoveNext
   rcdreclamation.MoveFirst

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: On which line, do you see "Invalid use of property"?

Comment: rcdreclamation.Fields![ClaimStatus] = "c" in this line

Comment: and highlighting the [ClaimStatus]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code above, I see problem with this line of code

```
Set rc2.Fields![ClaimStatus] = "c"
```

You don't need `Set` here.
It should have been `rc2.Fields![ClaimStatus] = "c"` (if this is the problematic line).

EDIT: I saw your reply to my question. And the same rule applies to the line in question.

Instead of
`Set rcdreclamation.Fields![ClaimStatus] = "c"`
it should be
`rcdreclamation.Fields![ClaimStatus] = "c"`

EDIT2: `Set` is needed when you are assigning to an object variable, an object instance or `Nothing`.

EDIT3: Also, you could write 
`rcdreclamation![ClaimStatus]` instead of `rcdreclamation.Fields![ClaimStatus]` for each such line.
(**disclaimer**: I hope I am right on my VB6 syntax. Its been quite some time).

Comment: yes, you are right. Thanks For your help. I have one more question. after updating that info how to save the data that i have modified into sql table ?

Comment: Please put in simple words, what you are trying to do? Are you trying to read a text file (CSV, tab separated) and wanting to INSERT those records into a SQL database?

Comment: No I already did that. I read the text file and insert those value into a table tb1. Now I want compare tb1 values with another table tb2. if tb1.rt1 = tb2.rt2 then cstatus =c, date = now. After that how to update this values in the table2. I hope you got my view. If not let me know I will explain clearly.

Comment: Instead of doing comparison by looping through recordset, you could do an UPDATE instead. e.g. UPDATE table2, table1 set table2.cstatus = 'C', table2.date = currentTime WHERE table2.rt2 = table1.rt1 (roughly, this is what I could think when looked at your comment above).